# Pandas parse json in column and expand to new rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing (record formatted) json strings as follows:

```
In[9]: pd.DataFrame( {'col1': ['A','B'], 'col2': ['[{"t":"05:15","v":"20.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"25.0"}]', 
                                                '[{"t":"05:15","v":"10.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"15.0"}]']})

Out[9]: 
  col1                                               col2
0    A  [{"t":"05:15","v":"20.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"2...
1    B  [{"t":"05:15","v":"10.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"1...
```

I would like to extract the json and for each record add a new row to the dataframe:

```
    co1 t           v
0   A   05:15:00    20
1   A   05:20:00    25
2   B   05:15:00    10
3   B   05:20:00    15
```

I've been experimenting with the following code:

```
def json_to_df(x):
    df2 = pd.read_json(x.col2)
    return df2

df.apply(json_to_df, axis=1)
```

but the resulting dataframes are assigned as tuples, rather than creating new rows. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, taking a little inspiration from hellpanderrr's answer above, I came up with the following:

```
In [92]:
pd.DataFrame( {'X': ['A','B'], 'Y': ['fdsfds','fdsfds'], 'json': ['[{"t":"05:15","v":"20.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"25.0"}]', 
                                                                       '[{"t":"05:15","v":"10.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"15.0"}]']},)
Out[92]:
    X   Y       json
0   A   fdsfds  [{"t":"05:15","v":"20.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"2...
1   B   fdsfds  [{"t":"05:15","v":"10.0"}, {"t":"05:20","v":"1...

In [93]:
dfs = []
def json_to_df(row, json_col):
    json_df = pd.read_json(row[json_col])
    dfs.append(json_df.assign(**row.drop(json_col)))
 
_.apply(json_to_df, axis=1, json_col='json')
pd.concat(dfs)

Out[93]:
    t       v   X   Y
0   05:15   20  A   fdsfds
1   05:20   25  A   fdsfds
0   05:15   10  B   fdsfds
1   05:20   15  B   fdsfds
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `apply` is that you need to return mulitple rows and it expects only one. A possible solution:

```
def json_to_df(row):
    _, row = row
    df_json = pd.read_json(row.col2)
    col1 = pd.Series([row.col1]*len(df_json), name='col1')
    return pd.concat([col1,df_json],axis=1)
df = map(json_to_df, df.iterrows())      #returns a list of dataframes
df = reduce(lambda x,y:x.append(y), x)   #glues them together
df

col1    t   v
0   A   05:15   20
1   A   05:20   25
0   B   05:15   10
1   B   05:20   15
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice hellpanderrr. I think what I needed to know is that it's not possible to reassign different dimensions in an apply function. I also needed a way to generically assign the remaining columns to the new groups. In the end I came up with the technique shown in my answer. Cheers