# how to transform column with special format in dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

i have my column json in this format :

```
"{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}"
"{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}"
"{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}"
"{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}"
```

i want to transforme this in pandas dataframe

```
id               time           number
7          1572741353685        003477
7          1572741353685        003477
7          1572741353685        003477
7          1572741353685        003477
```

i use loop for for do this but i want to do this without loop .
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas parse json in column and expand to new rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481961/pandas-parse-json-in-column-and-expand-to-new-rows-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
import ast


data = ["{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}","{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}","{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}","{'id': '7', 'time': 1572741353685, 'number': '003477'}"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A'])
df_result = pd.DataFrame(df["A"].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())
print(df_result)
```

**Output:**

```
  id           time  number
0  7  1572741353685  003477
1  7  1572741353685  003477
2  7  1572741353685  003477
3  7  1572741353685  003477
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like next should work in your case:

```
json_rows = [
...
]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    json.loads(row) for row in json_rows
])
```

Of course, it's still have loops at JSON parsing stage...

*UPD. And it's not a JSON - it's other representation of python object so you should replace `json.loads` with ast, as in other answers.*

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with convert values to dicts by [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df["col"]])
print(df)

  id           time  number
0  7  1572741353685  003477
1  7  1572741353685  003477
2  7  1572741353685  003477
3  7  1572741353685  003477
```