# Pandas json column store as nested dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have data-frame which contains json column and is quiet huge and is not very efficient, i would like to store it as nested data frame.

So sample data-frame looks like:

```
id                       date                                                                                                                                              ag                                                                                         marks
0  I2213 2022-01-01 13:28:05.448054  [{'type': 'A', 'values': {'X': {'F1': 0.1, 'F2': 0.2}, 'U': {'F1': 0.3, 'F2': 0.4}}}, {'type': 'B', 'results': {'Y': {'F1': 0.3, 'F2': 0.2}}}]            [{'type': 'A', 'marks': {'X': 0.5, 'U': 0.7}}, {'type': 'B', 'marks': {'Y': 0.4}}]
1  I2213 2022-01-01 14:28:05.448054                                                                                        [{'type': 'B', 'values': {'Z': {'F1': 0.4, 'F2': 0.2}}}]  [{'type': 'A', 'marks': {'X': 0.4, 'U': 0.6}}, {'type': 'B', 'marks': {'Y': 0.3, 'Z': 0.4}}]
2  I2213 2022-01-03 15:28:05.448054                                                                                        [{'type': 'A', 'values': {'X': {'F1': 0.2, 'F2': 0.1}}}]            [{'type': 'A', 'marks': {'X': 0.2, 'U': 0.9}}, {'type': 'B', 'marks': {'Y': 0.2}}]
```

Expected output:
[image]

grouped by date. Sample code for generating sample dataframe:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def sample_data():
    ag_data = [
        "[{'type': 'A', 'values': {'X': {'F1': 0.1, 'F2': 0.2}, 'U': {'F1': 0.3, 'F2': 0.4}}}, {'type': 'B', 'results': {'Y': {'F1': 0.3, 'F2': 0.2}}}]",
        "[{'type': 'B', 'values': {'Z': {'F1': 0.4, 'F2': 0.2}}}]",
        "[{'type': 'A', 'values': {'X': {'F1': 0.2, 'F2': 0.1}}}]",
    ]
    marks_data = [
         "[{'type': 'A', 'marks': {'X': 0.5, 'U': 0.7}}, {'type': 'B', 'marks': {'Y': 0.4}}]",
         "[{'type': 'A', 'marks': {'X': 0.4, 'U': 0.6}}, {'type': 'B', 'marks': {'Y': 0.3, 'Z': 0.4}}]",
         "[{'type': 'A', 'marks': {'X': 0.2, 'U': 0.9}}, {'type': 'B', 'marks': {'Y': 0.2}}]",
    ]
    date_data = [
        datetime.now() - timedelta(3, seconds=7200),
        datetime.now() - timedelta(3, seconds=3600),
        datetime.now() - timedelta(1),
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['date'] = date_data
    df['ag'] = ag_data
    df['marks'] = marks_data
    df['id'] = 'I2213'
    return df
```

I tried with json normalization, but it's creating dataframe in columnar fashion like:

```
d = a['ag'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(json.loads(x.replace("'", '"'))))
```

gives dataframe with columns  `type  values.X.F1  values.X.F2  values.U.F1  values.U.F2  results.Y.F1  results.Y.F2` issue is how to put dict keys like X,Y, F1,F2 as rows instead of columns.

Is it possible to achieve the desired format as shown in image?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you, it seems doing something similar for a much simpler JSON structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32486449/1703619

Comment: Reshaping Columns -> rows => Use `melt`.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt   or `stack` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking

Comment: Can you please edit the question and provide the code create sample dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by creating helper function.

```
def ag_col_helper(ag_df):
    s = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(ag_df.replace("\'", "\"")))
    s.set_index('type', inplace=True)
    s1 = s.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='feature')
    split_vals = s1['feature'].str.split(".", n = 2, expand = True)
    s1['name'] = split_vals[1]
    s1['feature'] =  split_vals[2]
    return s1.groupby(['type', 'name', 'feature']).first().dropna()


def marks_col_helper(marks_df):
    s = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(marks_df.replace("\'", "\"")))
    s.set_index('type', inplace=True)
    s1 = s.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='name', value_name='marks')
    split_vals = s1['name'].str.split(".", n = 2, expand = True)
    s1['name'] = split_vals[1]
    return s1.groupby(['type', 'name']).first().dropna()
```

Then this can be applied to the column `ag`

```
df['ag'] = df['ag'].apply(lambda x: do_something(x))
df['marks'] = df['marks'].apply(lambda x: do_something_marks(x))[0]
```

Then we would get for

```
df.iloc[0]['ag']

                   value
type name feature       
A    U    F1         0.3
          F2         0.4
     X    F1         0.1
          F2         0.2
B    Y    F1         0.3
          F2         0.2

df.iloc[0]['marks']

           marks
type name       
A    U       0.7
     X       0.5
B    Y       0.4
```

I think this one is what you are expecting.

For grouping the date column you can create another column using `df['Date'] = df['date'].dt.date` and perform a groupby.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can set data frames as values within a dataframe. This:

```
import pandas as pd

#creating outer df
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b':2, 'inner':None},{'a':3, 'b':4, 'inner':None}])

#creating inner dfs
inner_1 = pd.DataFrame([{'time': 0, 'e': 1}, {'time': 1, 'e': 2}])
inner_2 = pd.DataFrame([{'time': 0, 'e': 6}, {'time': 1, 'e': 7}])
inners = [inner_1, inner_2]

df['inner'] = inners
print(df)
```

results in this:

```
   a  b       inner
0  1  2        time  e
           0     0  1
           1     1  2
1  3  4        time  e
           0     0  6
           1     1  7
```

the print out quickly gets confusing, but it seems like it's what you want.

for your data specifically, take your lists of dicts and convert them to a `df` with `pd.DataFrame`. If you want to turn all your lists to dataframes, you can use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

#creating outer df
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b':2, 'inner':None},{'a':3, 'b':4, 'inner':None}])

#creating inner dfs
inner_1 = [{'time': 0, 'e': 1}, {'time': 1, 'e': 2}]
inner_2 = [{'time': 0, 'e': 6}, {'time': 1, 'e': 7}]
inners = [inner_1, inner_2]

df['inner'] = inners
print('un-transformed')
print(df)

#transforming all lists into DFs
for i in range(df.shape[0]): #iterate over rows
    for j in range(df.shape[1]): #iterate over columns
        if type(df.iat[i,j]) == list: #filtering cells that are lists
            df.iat[i, j] = pd.DataFrame(df.iat[i, j]) #convert to df

print("transformed")
print(df)
```

which returns

```
un-transformed
   a  b                                       inner
0  1  2  [{'time': 0, 'e': 1}, {'time': 1, 'e': 2}]
1  3  4  [{'time': 0, 'e': 6}, {'time': 1, 'e': 7}]
transformed
   a  b       inner
0  1  2        time  e
           0     0  1
           1     1  2
1  3  4        time  e
           0     0  6
           1     1  7
```